# Laravel migration array type (store array in database column)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, types, laravel-5.1

I want to store an array of integers in my table and I can't find any type that supports array in **[Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#creating-columns)**, any suggestion.

**Migration:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pickups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increment('id');
        $table->boolean('default');
        $table->integer('shifts');  <<--------- HERE I want to store an array of integers
        $table->integer('status_id');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The `array` datatype is not present in all database systems and because Laravel's Schema Builder is database agnostic, it doesn't offer methods to create non-common datatype columns. So you have two options:

**1.** Use a raw SQL statement to add the column, something like the statement below I think should work. Although I'm not sure if the Query Builder or Eloquent can handle these types of columns correctly:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE pickups ADD COLUMN shifts integer[]');
```

**2.** Use Eloquent's available workaround by using [attribute casting](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting). In your migration create the column as `json` like so:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pickups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increment('id');
        $table->boolean('default');
        $table->json('shifts');
        $table->integer('status_id');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then you can setup your `Pickup` model (if you haven't done so already) and use the `$casts` property:

```
class Pickup extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'shifts' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

This will let Eloquent know that when it fetches data from the database it will have to convert the `shifts` column value to an `array`. This is only emulating an actual array, as at the database level the column is of type `TEXT` and the array is serialized. However when unserializing the column value, Eloquent returns an actual array of integers for you to use in your code. Below is an example use case:

```
// Create a new Pickup entry
$pickup = App\Pickup::create([
    'default' => true,
    'shifts' => '[1, 5, 7]', // you can easily assign an actual integer array here
    'status_id' => 1
]);
```

Assuming the above generated an entry with `id` equal to `1` when you later retrieve the entry:

```
$pickup = App\Pickup::find(1);
dump($pickup->shifts);
```

The `dump()` from the code above will output an actual array of integers:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 5
  2 => 7
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan for your greate answer, unfortunately when i try to create new pickup entry with  `'shifts' => [1, 5, 7],` i receive this error msg `PHP warning:  preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array`.

Comment: okay now it's work like following `'shifts' => '[1, 5, 7]',`, thanks :)

Comment: I've tested this with a clean install of Laravel 5.1 and for me it actually works without placing quotes around the array when assigning the value.

Comment: Would querying work in this case and how? E.g. I want all records that contain shift 5.

Comment: Yes, @MarinLeontenko, querying is the catch. I was able to easily create a JSON column in postgresql and cast to array in the model, and you can easily get the data out, but I have failed so far to find a way to successfully do what you ask.

Answer (score 7):

There is another more complicated approach, but it allows to create truly native arrays using the schema builder.

Example for PostgreSQL.

1. Register new `int_array` type which will resolve into `int[]` by extending the existing DB Schema Grammar:

```php
\DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new class extends PostgresGrammar {
    protected function typeInt_array(\Illuminate\Support\Fluent $column)
    {
        return 'int[]';
    }
});
```

You can put this code right inside the migration if you need it just once or into `AppServiceProvider` to make it available in whole project.

2. Now you can use this type in your migrations:

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->addColumn('int_array', 'group_ids')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I liked this the best :) God bless!

Answer (score 2):

I generally store array in the column as a comma-separated string and retrieve it with explode.

So in your case while storing I would dod something like this:

```
$arraystring = implode(',',$array);

$pickups->shifts = $arraystring; //$pickups is an instance of your Pickups model.

//Then while retrieving I would just use;

$array = $pickups->shifts ? explode(',',$pickups-shifts) : []; 
/*just to make sure it is not an empty string 
else you will get an error on explode.*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, store your array integer with json:

```
$table->json('shifts');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add :

```
protected $cast=['shifts'=>'array'];
```

in your model class, it work for me with laravel 8.